# Null object reference exception while calling mediaplayer methods

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, media-player

I am getting this error while calling my `player.pause();` method in my application. I am pausing music using ImageButton. I am calling method from `song_list` class to pause the track. But, following exception occurs:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.pause()' on a null object reference

My MainActivity:

```
public class MusicKom extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = "PermissionDemo";
    public static final int REQUEST_READ_STORAGE = 112;
    private ImageButton btplay;
    private ImageButton pausemusic;

    public void playbutton(int playbuttonid){

        btplay=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
        btplay.setBackgroundResource(playbuttonid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_kom);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
        final viewpageadapter adapter = new viewpageadapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        Button bt2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.album_list);
        Button bt3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.artist_list);
        pausemusic = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);


        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });

        bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }
        });

        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            }
        });

        pausemusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               songs_list sl=new songs_list();
               sl.pauseplay();
               pausemusic.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My song_list Fragment:

```
public class songs_list extends Fragment {

    // Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget.
    private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;
    public MediaPlayer player;
    private String currentFile="";
    private boolean isStarted = true;
    private TextView selelctedFile = null;
    private View v=null;
    private String selectedtitem=null;
    private int fileposition;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        player = new MediaPlayer();

        // Use cursor to get data from external resource

        final Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);


        // check Cursor has data or not

        if (null != cursor) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_layout, cursor);
            v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_songs_list, container, false);

            ListView lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


            lv.setAdapter(mediaAdapter);



            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    selectedtitem = (String) view.getTag();
                    startPlay(selectedtitem);
                }
            });


        }


        return v;
    }

    private void startPlay(String file) {

        player.stop();
        player.reset();

        try {
            player.setDataSource(file);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ((MusicKom) getActivity()).playbutton(R.drawable.play);
    }

    public void pauseplay(){
        Log.i(TAG, "pauseplay: ");
        player.pause();
    }
}
```

Comment: `logcat` please. Your `player` is null. How are you passing `player` to another activity?

Comment: sorry it was not full code. try now.

Answer (score 0):

How can you call another activity method without actually launching the activity. In your case the another activity is not loaded and hence media player object is not created.

please post the whole code to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Fragment as a regular java class. Fragment's `onCreateView()` is not called when you instantiate Fragment. It is only called when you show a fragment with a valid FragmentTranscation. See [Fragment Life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Comment down if you want the fragment to show up when you have to call `pauseplay();`, I will add the relevant code.

Otherwise, you should be using a regular java class to create and play/pause a media player from anywhere. Something like:

```
// package com.example.package_name;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class SoundPlayer {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    // rawSongId is in form of 'R.id.song_name'
    public SoundPlayer(Context context, int rawSongId){
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, rawSongId);
    }

    public SoundPlayer(Context context, String dataSource){
        // handle media player with your data source
    }

    public void start(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    public void pause(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    public void stop(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop(); // reset(); ? 
        }
    }

}
```

Now, instead of

```
songs_list sl = new songs_list();
sl.pauseplay();
```

you can,

```
String dataSource = ""; // generate your dataSource here

// initialize MediaPlayer with dataSource
SoundPlayer soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(this, dataSource);

// Use its methods
soundPlayer.start();
soundPlayer.pause();
soundPlayer.stop();
```

please try to use proper [camelCase coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Your `pauseplay()` should be `pausePlay();` or `pauseOrPlay()`.

Comment: not working !! showing error in mainactivity cannot resolve constructor

Comment: E/MediaPlayer: pause called in state 1
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)